# Login to linux box with putty using public ssh key

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

A hosting provider sent me a public key and the hostname of a linux box which I want to ssh into. Now usually, I simply input the hostname in putty and then type username and password, but now I just have the hostname and the public key (which ends with `username@ssh1`)

I was curious if there is a way to log into the server using only what I have? Since it's weekend, I can't contact them for the additional info, hence this question.

Comment: putty can use the public keys ill post how to do it in minnute

Comment: I think you will need the private key to connect. The public key should be uploaded to the linux box that you want to ssh into.

Answer (score 0):

- OPen putty
- type ip and port and make a saved name for it
- click the plus on connection
- click the plus on ssh
- click on auth
- click browse find your public key
- go back to connection and save then open

Comment: putty asks for a private key

Comment: it can use the public one, if aint letting you post back

Comment: it's not letting me use the public key

Comment: does it end .ppk?

Comment: it ends with .pub

Comment: that key should be on the server you need one that ends ppk

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense the provider sends this key to you.

The `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in your profile, which can be read by anyone who has `root` access to that server, contains *public* keys, one per line. If you have the matching *private* key for one of the public keys, you can login.

The private key is called *private* because it is *yours*; you are the one to create it (e.g. with `puttygen`), and send the matching public key *to the server admin*.

Thus, the private key is present on *your* own machine only, and nobody but you knows it.  If an admin sent it to you, he would know it, and it wouldn't be private.

You can choose a passphrase for your key; at least if using it on a machine which might get lost, like a laptop, you should definitely do so.  For convenience, you can load your key into `pageant`; that way you need to enter the passphrase only once.